# Parsing Single JSON object in Android Studio

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON Object I want to parse at  this URL https://api.adviceslip.com/advice with this content:
{"slip": { "id": 137, "advice": "You're not that important; it's what you do that counts."}}

I have written this code in Android Studio but it does not seem to work.

```
String jsonString = handler.httpServiceCall(url);
            if (jsonString != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

                    JSONObject slip = jsonObject.getJSONObject("slip");

                    String id = slip.getString("id");
                    Log.d("slip id:", id);
                    String advice = slip.getString("advice");
                    Log.d("slip adv:", advice);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("id", id);
                    map.put("advice", advice);
                    adviceSlip.setText(map.get("advice"));



                }
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What's the error you getting?

Comment: `but it does not seem to work.` what does it do ? what does it not do ? breakpoints ? logs ?

Comment: `slip.getInt("id");`

Comment: I want to get the "advice" and set that text in TextView adviceSlip.

Comment: @swishy check my answer and if it doesn't solve your problem post the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you are trying to get a `String` on an `Int` object, and perhaps this is one of your errors, please change your

```
splip.getString("id");
```

by

```
slip.getInt("id);
```

Another one is that you are creating a `HashMap<String,String>` but the id you getting from the `json` is an `Int` and perhaps you should change it to use `HashMap<Int,String>`

Answer (score -1):

```
 You can get the value from the jsonobject and simple set that value on the textview. 
   

   String jsonString = handler.httpServiceCall(url);
    if (jsonString != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

            JSONObject slip = jsonObject.getJSONObject("slip");

            String id = slip.getString("id");
            Log.d("slip id:", id);
            String advice = slip.getString("advice");
            adviceSlip.setText(advice);



        }
```